# torrents downloaded using python urllib2 fail to open in bittorrent client

Tags: python, bittorrent

I've been using python to download torrents for some time but for about a week or more, those torrent files have stopped opening in transmission. Here is the code:

```
torrent = urllib2.urlopen(torrent URL, timeout = 30)
output = open('mytorrent.torrent', 'wb')
output.write(torrent.read())
```

This used to work fine in the past but now it won't load in transmission. I tried another client 'tixati' which threw up an error "error parsing meta-file". If I download the torrent file via browser, it opens fine in both clients. I've tried changing file options to `output = open('mytorrent.torrent', 'w')` but the result is the same.

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Have you diffed the browser and Python versions of the same torrent?

Comment: how do i diff b/w them? these files don't contain text and cannot be opened by a text editor. gedit shows gibberish when i try to open both original and self-created files.

Comment: A fair point. I forgot they were binary data. You could convert them to [hex for comparison](http://superuser.com/questions/125376/how-do-i-compare-binary-files-in-linux) but it's going to become harder to spot what the original difference was. I *suspect* Python is encoding them as something they're not intended to be.

Comment: Could this be the same issue as mentioned in this question: [Downloading a torrent file with WebClient, results in corrupt file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857709/downloading-a-torrent-file-with-webclient-results-in-corrupt-file) ?

Comment: Ok, i can confirm its the same problem as mentioned in the question link above. although the torrent url ends with '.torrent' suffix, it is actually zipped with gzip. Once I unzip the downloaded file using gunzip, the torrent file starts working normally. I need to code python to look up file encoding and unzip the file using the appropriate tool...How do I do that?

Comment: I have found that certain torrent clients will handle the zipped files on their own. If I remember correctly, Deluge is one of them. (and is fairly lightweight but well featured). I know that on Android aTorrent does as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`urllib2` does exactly what it's told and won't automatically decompress content streams. Thankfully, [that bit isn't too hard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3947241/12870).

Additionally if you're always using the same server, you could skip the check for gzip encoding.

```
from io import BytesIO
import gzip

torrent = urllib2.urlopen(torrentURL, timeout=30)
buffer = BytesIO(torrent.read())
gz = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=buffer)
output = open('mytorrent.torrent', 'wb')
output.write(gz.read())
```

I've subbed in `io.BytesIO` to keep this compatible with Python 3.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "unzip_torrent.py", line 13, in <module>
    output.write(gz.read())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 249, in read
    self._read(readsize)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 283, in _read
    pos = self.fileobj.tell()   # Save current position
AttributeError: addinfourl instance has no attribute 'tell'`